# I need help from a native english speaker to check description for my game

Tags: html5-canvas, game-physics

I need help from a native english speaker to check description for my game. The game is called "slingshot", and here is the description:

In this exciting game you have to control a catapult. Your goal is to get into a penguin, spending as little snowballs as possible. You have to complete dozens of different levels, from the most simple to the more complex. To succeed, you will be required accurate shooting and cold calculation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This site is devoted to asking and answering questions specifically about programming.  A better site to post this question is: http://english.stackexchange.com/ which is dedicated to questions about the English language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about natural language usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this exciting game you have to control a catapult.

A comma is needed in this sentence. Also, "have to" is unnecessary and sounds strange (you are making it into a command, whereas you really want to describe what happens in present tense).

I recommend changing that sentence to:

> In this exciting game, you control a catapult.

OR:

> In this exciting game, you have control over a catapult.

(Which might have been the original intention).

> Your goal is to get into a penguin

Get "into" a penguin? What does that mean? This doesn't make any sense.

> spending as little snowballs as possible.

Change "little" to "few" (little is for continuous values, while "few" is for discrete values).

> from the most simple to the more complex.

These need to be parallel. Use "from the simplest to the most complex".

> To succeed, you will be required accurate shooting and cold calculation.

Change this to: "To succeed will require accurate shooting and cold calculation."